# How to create two or more matrices from a single one under certain conditions?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

Hello I am new in matlab and I cannot figure out how to solve a problem.

I have Matrix1:

```
1   0
2   334.456
3   654.7654
4   65.76543
1   0
2   543.43567
3   98.432
4   54.9876
5   12.456
```

and Matrix2:

```
1   2
2   3
3   4
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

Matrix2 represents the links found in Matrix1 in the order they appear.

I would like to separate the links in blocks (matrices) where each block starts from stop 1. So by analysing Matrix2 I should produce 2 new matrices one with the links (1,2)(2,3)(3,4) and the other with the links (1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5). 
So that each time I find the stop 1, it starts building a new matrix.
I would like `A` and `B` to come out as:

```
A= [1,2, 334.456; 2,3,654.7654;3,4,65.76543]
B=[1,2,543.43567;2,3,98.432;3,4,54.9876;4,5,12.456]
```

Comment: In your example, you did not actually build TWO distinct matrices. Is your goal to build a single matrix of the form you show?

Comment: Creating MULTIPLE named matrices is generally a bad thing to do, unless you will be happy with a cell array of matrices, which I would strongly suggest.

Comment: Please provide a clear example. What do both matrices look like? Should they contain the entries `Matrix1(1,2)`, `Matrix1(2,3)` and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this does what you want. `matrices` is a cell array containing the amount of distinct matrices that are required (based on the amount of 1's in column 1 of Matrix2).

```
Matrix1=[1 0; 2   334.456;3   654.7654;4   65.76543;1   0;2   543.43567;3   98.432;4   54.9876;5   12.456];
Matrix2=[1   2; 2   3; 3   4; 1   2; 2   3; 3   4; 4   5];

rows=find(Matrix2(:,1)==1); % find row numbers with 1 in column 1 of matrix 2)
rows=[rows(2:end); size(Matrix2,1)+1]; % ignore (obvious) first row, add end of Matrix2
nrows=size(rows,1);

matrices=cell(nrows,1);
for i=1:nrows
    lb=1;
    if i>1
        lb=rows(i-1);
    end
    matrices{i,1}=zeros(rows(i)-lb,3);
    for j=lb:rows(i)-1
        matrices{i,1}(j-lb+1,:)=[Matrix2(j,:), Matrix1(lb+Matrix2(j,2)-2+i,2)];
    end
end
```

With the following result:

```
>> matrices{1,1}

ans =

    1.0000    2.0000  334.4560
    2.0000    3.0000  654.7654
    3.0000    4.0000   65.7654

>> matrices{2,1}

ans =

    1.0000    2.0000  543.4357
    2.0000    3.0000   98.4320
    3.0000    4.0000   54.9876
    4.0000    5.0000   12.4560
```

Comment: Sorry, but this was not the question at all. Look carefully at the example.

Comment: I think `Matrix2` was an output not an input, but it wouldn't be hard to just use `Matrix1`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful.

```
  Matrix1 = [
    1   0
    2   334.456
    3   654.7654
    4   65.76543
    1   0
    2   543.43567
    3   98.432
    4   54.9876
    5   12.456
  ];

  result = {};
  index = 1;
  temp = [];
  prev = [];

  for i=1:size(Matrix1)(1)
    if (Matrix1(i, 1) == 1)
      if (~isempty(temp))
        result{index++} = temp;
        temp = [];
      end
      prev = Matrix1(i, 1:2);
    else
      curr = Matrix1(i, 1:2);
      val = [prev(1), curr(1), curr(2)];
      prev = curr;

      temp = [temp; val;];
    end
  end

  if (~isempty(temp))
    result{index} = temp;  
  end

  result
```